# What are images of objects with dimensions shown called?

Tags: product-design, research

[image]

You see these images a lot on e-commerce websites like Amazon. I want to search for these images on google and I don't know the exact wording for these type of images, or if there is one. Please tell me what terms I should search for if I want to find images that show the product in relation to human height. I have already tried many obvious searches.

Comment: Perhaps the terms you are looking for are "schematic diagram" or "product dimensions diagram".

Comment: try to search google images for = human scale "your subject" diagram.
eg= human scale chair diagram

Comment: You mention that you “already tried many obvious searches.” If you add what you tried to the question, it would be easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @nishantkumar I tried the human scale search and it worked the best of all the others. and I also have come to the conclusion that perhaps there is no particular name for such type of images or at least not yet. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [Orthographic drawings/projections](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/333547916135570195/?lp=true). You can always photoshop a picture of a human and it's height besides the images.

I don't think you will find an archive of dimensioned specified objects next to a dimensioned human though.

Comment: I knew that I would have to use photoshop I also knew how to create the images wasn't  a hard task. I just wanted to know if there's any particular term for such images so that I could just search on google and show to the client and he can then just pick a style for his brand. and I knew I could find these images on Amazon but you kind of have to do a lot of trial and error just to find those specific kinds of images on Amazon. as a conclusion of this, I have found out that human scale and "your subject" seems to work better than most search terms. & there is no specific name for such images.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are searching for something like this:
https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d4/bc/70/d4bc702cce51856f9849e61fe41df708--human-figures-concept-diagram.jpg

Either way, you should use the search terms: person, dimensions, schematics, table (for example).

Comment: May be also "ergonomics [+ product type]"

Comment: for my question, the search term human scale followed by the subject name seems to work best. thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For the guy a search for `silhouette drawings people` would do. For the tables `dimensions side view` would be a description that an architect would use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this incorrectly. The idea is to make your own. These are likely done in 3D modeling software and then added a human for scale. Engineers and Architects often have libraries of things like people to use in renderings and visualizations.

If you want to do it with product photography you should take your photo of the product and use a raster image editor to superimpose a human and a scale on it yourself.

A quick search on any number of stock websites for "people silhouettes" will get you a decent catalog to work with: [Shutterstock: 106273379](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/people-silhouette-black-vector-girl-man-106273379?src=Y3srFdEyrAzP6Q86YoTWHg-1-7)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question correctly. the question was not how I can create such images the question was what are those images called which are everywhere on Amazon yet you can't search them because nobody knows what they are called I just wanted to search some reference images for the client to choose.  but I didn't know what to search. it seems the closest answer is human scale and your subject. and there is no definitive name for such type of images.